# Html Id question

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, automapper

I have something like this

```
public class Reminders()
{
   public List<SelectListItem> Reminder { get; set; }
   public string SelectedReminder { get; set; }
}
```

Now I want to make a List of Reminder classes that contain what I have above.

```
List<Reminders> reminders = new List<Reminders>();
// add SelectListItems somehow through auto mapper( not sure how to do)
// add reminders into my viewModel
```

Then in my view I would need to loop through them to generate the dropdown list. So the idea is that say if I want a user to be able to set 5 reminder then I just make sure my collection has 5 reminders.

If I want them only to have 1, I make sure the collection has one reminder. If I want 100 then I change it to a 100. So by doing this I future proofed that area as it can expand or decrease very easily.

Now before I try to go make this and try to figure out how to do it with automapper I am wondering how can I make each dropdown list have its own id? Like right now I can see they will all have same id("SelectedReminder").

Of course this is bad since you should only have one id per html page. So how can I make them have different ids?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using an editor template you shouldn't worry about this because all naming convention will be handled correctly by the framework. You also shouldn't need to do any *looping*. So suppose that you have a controller action that returns an `IEnumerable<Reminders>` and you want to generate a list of dropdowns:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var reminders = new[]
    {
        new Reminders 
        {
            Reminder = new List<SelectListItem> 
            { 
                new SelectListItem { Value = "1", Text = "reminder 1" },
                new SelectListItem { Value = "2", Text = "reminder 2" },
            },
        },
        new Reminders
        {
            Reminder = new List<SelectListItem> 
            { 
                new SelectListItem { Value = "1", Text = "reminder 1" },
                new SelectListItem { Value = "2", Text = "reminder 2" },
                new SelectListItem { Value = "3", Text = "reminder 3" },
            },
        }
    };
    return View(reminders);
}
```

Then in your view you would simply:

```
@model IEnumerable<AppName.Models.Reminders>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.EditorForModel()
    <input type="submit" value="OK" />
}
```

and the corresponding editor template (`~/Views/Home/EditorTemplates/Reminders.cshtml`):

```
@model AppName.Models.Reminders
@Html.DropDownListFor(
    x => x.SelectedReminder, 
    new SelectList(Model.Reminder, "Value", "Text")
)
```

Because you sent 2 elements in the view model there will be 2 dropdowns generated each with a correct name so that when you post back you would get the corresponding selected values:

```
<select name="[0].SelectedReminder">
    <option value="1">reminder 1</option>
    <option value="2">reminder 2</option>
</select>

<select name="[1].SelectedReminder">
    <option value="1">reminder 1</option>
    <option value="2">reminder 2</option>
    <option value="3">reminder 3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I am having problems getting that working since my view is a bit different. My strongly type view is a ViewModel that contains a List Of ReminderViewModels that contains the contents of the Reminder class that I posted in my OP. So reminder class is actually my ViewModel.

Comment: I should also add that ReminderViewModel also will contain other selectList items to generate other dropdown lists that are needed.

Comment: @chobo2, in this case instead of `@Html.EditorForModel()` in your view you would have `@Html.EditorFor(x => x.ReminderViewModels)` where `ReminderViewModels` is a property of your view model of type `IEnumerable<Reminders>`. Then you could also have some other `EditorFor` inside the form.

Comment: I tried to do that but it did not like the complex data or something. I had to do in my template a forloop and then do something like @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x[i].SelectedReminder, new SelectList(Model[i].Reminder,"Value","Text"))

Comment: I can't figure out how to do it without using a forloop inside my template.